# Providing fields for every id through network in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am sorry for re-posting this old question of mine but it has not been quite solved and the older post was getting long and confusing.

[image]

So, the issue is the one described below basically. A very good reply to the problem was given to me by applying network theory and namely performing this:

```
# generate exploded version of DataFrame to be able to construct the graph
df2 = (result2_min.loc[m]
        .explode(['citing_patents', 'dist_citing_patents'])
      )

# build the directed graph with weights
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2.rename(columns={'dist_citing_patents': 'weight'}),
                           source='docdb_family_id', target='citing_patents',
                           edge_attr='weight',
                           create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find closest leaf for each node
def distance(n, leaf):
   try:
       return nx.dijkstra_path_length(G, n, leaf, weight='weight')
   except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
       return float('inf')

mapper = {n: min(leafs, key=lambda leaf: distance(n, leaf)) for n in G.nodes}

# map leaf to field
fields = result2_min[~m].set_index('docdb_family_id')['oecd_fields']

# map each node to terminal leafs to field
result2_min['New_var'] = result2_min['Cited_patents'].map(mapper).map(fields)
```

however, my data frame contains 9 Million observations, and this part takes forever to run:

```
mapper = {n: min(leafs, key=lambda leaf: distance(n, leaf)) for n in G.nodes}
```

Hence I was curious about whether there could be either another "less computationally expensive" solution or a workaround to re-write the mapper code in a "linear-complex" way (O(n)).

I will leave you below the code for generating the mock example:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, [7,3], [1,1], ""], [2, [1,5], [2,1], "Math"], [3, [1,2,6], [2,0,2], ""],[4, [7], [1], "Science"],[5, [1,2], [2,0], ""],[6, [5,8], [1,1], ""],[7, [4,8], [0,1], ""],[8, [4], [0], ""]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['docdb', 'cited_patents','dist_cited_patents','Fields'])
```

Thank you

Comment: How similar is the actual data to your mock data in terms of the value of `dist_cited_patents`?  Are most just one or two away or are there some that would be in the hundreds/thousands?  Additionally, how many fields are there?  Is it closer to 10 or closer to 10,000?  I have some ideas for optimizations but they may not help too much if the actual data is significantly "deeper" or more interconnected than your sample data.

Comment: @Andrew the distance  (values in dist_cited_patents) arrive up to a maximum of 18. The lists in dist_cited_patents might contain up to 10000 values. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach of your interesting question, less sophisticated and probably less efficient on your real data than your current solution, but I would be interested to know anyway.

```py
def select_patents(dist, patents):
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        dist: distances of cited patents.
        patents: cited patents.

    Returns:
        Patents with minimum distance.

    """
    return [p for d, p in zip(dist, patents) if d == min(dist)]


# Find patents
df["selected_patents"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: select_patents(x["dist_cited_patents"], x["cited_patents"]), axis=1
)
df["new_var"] = df["fields"]

# Follow selected patents
while not df["new_var"].all():
    df["new_var"] = df.apply(
        lambda x: [
            df.loc[df["docdb_id"] == i, "new_var"].values[0]
            if not x["new_var"]
            else x["new_var"]
            for i in x["selected_patents"]
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    df["new_var"] = df.apply(
        lambda x: ""
        if (isinstance(x["new_var"], list) and not all(x["new_var"]))
        or not x["new_var"]
        else x["new_var"],
        axis=1,
    )

# Cleanup
df["new_var"] = df.apply(lambda x: [item[0] for item in x["new_var"]], axis=1)
df["new_var"] = df["new_var"].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x and len(x) == 1 else x)
```

```py
print(df)
   docdb_id cited_patents dist_cited_patents   fields          new_var
0         1        [7, 3]             [1, 1]           [Science, Math]
1         2        [1, 5]             [2, 1]     Math             Math
2         3     [1, 2, 6]          [2, 0, 2]                      Math
3         4           [7]                [1]  Science          Science
4         5        [1, 2]             [2, 0]                      Math
5         6        [5, 8]             [1, 1]           [Math, Science]
6         7        [4, 8]             [0, 1]                   Science
7         8           [4]                [0]                   Science
```